# What is the best way to implement a login system in a small website

Tags: asp.net

What is the best way to implement a login system in a small website?

I had a look at [Membership](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513220018/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx) in ASP.NET, but looks complicated for what I need.

Any recommendations on how to go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is it you need? Membership is probably the best "value for money/effort", especially for a "small website". Even gives you a nice UI to get it off the ground (ASP.NET Configuration in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio)

Comment: sure, I find the official learning materials pretty good at conveying concepts in a concise way: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/authentication and also http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security

Comment: Don't roll your own.  If you make a poorly implemented system, your users are likely to use the same old username/password they use everywhere else. And then when you get hacked, you've just given the bad guys all their logins because "Membership looks complicated."  Don't be that guy.  And check out the OWASP guide to authentication. (Google it. Learning to search OWASP is every web developer's sacred responsibility.)

Comment: And read this, too.  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use membership completely. You can use ASP.NET Forms authentication however and simply authenticate the user yourself against a database, file or whatever.

Microsoft provides an example here - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout sample programs using asp.net membership and forms authentication.

If you want to have your own implementation, Create a User table where you store the UserID/Name and password (Encrypted- Salted). When user tries to login, check againist this database and see whethe a record exist for the user credentials provided by the user. If yes, set his relevant credentials in the Session variable ( for future use across his user session) and send him to the relevant page.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you don't build your own authentication/membership framework, unless you have a good reason to do so.

The membership framework does allow extension if it doesn't provide everything you need.

I think it's worth understanding the membership provider before looking at alternatives, as it's quite simple. However, depending on your requirements you could use [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/).

Answer (score 0):

How small (users)? An even easier option to @Lloyd's answer (which you should consider over this depending on what you mean by "small"):

Define them in web.config itself:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".myWebSite">
    <credentials passwordFormat="MD5">
      <user name="user1" password="the_MD5Hash_of_user1_password"/>
      <user name="user2" password="the_MD5Hash_of_user2_password"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

You can opt for `passwordFormat` = `CLEAR` or `SHA1` and provide the clear text or Sha1 hash `password` value respectively.